How to run file 'INSTALL'
I need to run file "INSTALL".

This is the content of the file "INSTALL":
USERNAME=$(env | grep SUDO_USER | sed s/SUDO_USER=//g)
echo "User Name is:" $USERNAME 
mkdir /home/$USERNAME/.config/autostart/ 
chown $USERNAME:$USERNAME -R /home/$USERNAME/.config/autostart 
cp ./mirror_display.desktop /home/$USERNAME/.config/autostart/ 
chown $USERNAME:$USERNAME /home/$USERNAME/.config/autostart/mirror_display.desktop 
cp ./mirror_display.sh /usr/bin/ 
chown $USERNAME:$USERNAME /usr/bin/mirror_display.sh 
sync 
sync 
echo "Please reboot the system"

and after running the script:
User Name is:
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home//.config/autostart/’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access '/home//.config/autostart': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/home//.config/autostart/': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 
'/home//.config/autostart/mirror_display.desktop': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/bin/mirror_display.sh': Permission denied
chown: cannot access '/usr/bin/mirror_display.sh': No such file or directory
Please reboot the system


Open a terminal in the same directory (right click + "open a terminal here"), run chmod +x INSTALL and then ./INSTALL. No matter if it's a script or an executable it should run regardless.

@LâmVăn Please edit your original question and post the contents of these comments there. Otherwise, the comment is not formatted properly, and is very hard to read.

It looks like this script isn't picking up your username.  Did you run this as sudo or no?  If you did not, then the script can't install because it's not running as superuser AND isn't able to determine your username.

The problem is they are trying to be fancy but they end up being ugly.
They're unnecessarily assigning the value of SUDO_USER to USERNAME (in the ugliest most unnecessarily convoluted way I've seen, what about just USERNAME=$SUDO_USER?), potentially masking another environment variable (USERNAME) in the process, while they could've just used SUDO_USER in the first place.
And most importantly the script doesn't account for SUDO_USER possibly being unset, so the thing screams in pain if run without sudo.
It started with me wanting to fix just these two things but of course once you're there it gets out of hand and you want to fix everything, so I ended up rewriting the whole thing, stripping it also of some other nonsense such as the double sync and an unnecessary double chmod command: it also installs mirror_display.sh in a more reasonable way (in /usr/bin, leaving the ownership to root and with permissions 0755):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[ ! -z "${SUDO_USER}" ] || exit 1
[ $(id -u "${USER}") -eq 0 ] || exit 2

user_autostart_dir=/home/${SUDO_USER}/.config/autostart # assumes that the user's home directory is located in `/home` and that is named after the user, mostly safe
users_bin_dir=/usr/bin

printf "Installing for user: '%s'\n" "${SUDO_USER}"
printf "Installing in: '%s', '%s'\n" "${user_autostart_dir}" "${users_bin_dir}"

mkdir "${user_autostart_dir}" || exit 3 # assumes that '/home/${SUDO_USER}/.config' exists, '${user_autostart_dir}''s mode will depend on root's umask, mostly safe

cp mirror_display.desktop "${user_autostart_dir}"
chmod 700 "${user_autostart_dir}"/mirror_display.desktop
chown -R "${SUDO_USER}": "${user_autostart_dir}" # much like the original script, changes the ownership of '${user_autostart_dir}' recursively, should be always safe

cp mirror_display.sh "${users_bin_dir}"
chmod 755 "${users_bin_dir}"/mirror_display.sh

sync # overkill if the system really has to be rebooted

printf 'Done! Please reboot the system.\n' # does the system really have to be rebooted?


Awesome - a prime example of why you shouldn't just run install scripts, but actually try to undestand what's going on.
